# How to copy CosmosDb docs to Blob storage (each doc in single json file) with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to backup my Cosmos Db storage using Azure Data Factory(v2). In general, it's doing its job, but I want to have each doc in Cosmos collection to correspond new json file in blobs storage.

With next copying params i'm able to copy all docs in collection into 1 file in azure blob storage:

```
{
"name": "ForEach_mih",
"type": "ForEach",
"typeProperties": {
    "items": {
        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.cw_items",
        "type": "Expression"
    },
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Copy_mih",
            "type": "Copy",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [
                {
                    "name": "Source",
                    "value": "@{item().source.collectionName}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Destination",
                    "value": "cosmos-backup-v2/@{item().destination.fileName}"
                }
            ],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DocumentDbCollectionSource",
                    "nestingSeparator": "."
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "BlobSink"
                },
                "enableStaging": false,
                "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true,
                "redirectIncompatibleRowSettings": {
                    "linkedServiceName": {
                        "referenceName": "Clear_Test_BlobStorage",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    },
                    "path": "cosmos-backup-logs"
                },
                "cloudDataMovementUnits": 0
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "SourceDataset_mih",
                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                    "parameters": {
                        "cw_collectionName": "@item().source.collectionName"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "DestinationDataset_mih",
                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                    "parameters": {
                        "cw_fileName": "@item().destination.fileName"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

How I can copy each cosmos doc to separate file and give it name the as {PartitionId}-{docId}?

**UPD**

Source set code:

```
{
"name": "ClustersData",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "Clear_Test_CosmosDb",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "type": "DocumentDbCollection",
    "typeProperties": {
        "collectionName": "directory-clusters"
    }
}
}
```

Destination set code:

```
{
"name": "OutputClusters",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "Clear_Test_BlobStorage",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "typeProperties": {
        "format": {
            "type": "JsonFormat",
            "filePattern": "arrayOfObjects"
        },
        "fileName": "",
        "folderPath": "cosmos-backup-logs"
    }
}
}
```

Pipeline code:

```
{
"name": "copy-clsts",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "LookupClst",
            "type": "Lookup",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DocumentDbCollectionSource",
                    "nestingSeparator": "."
                },
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ClustersData",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "firstRowOnly": false
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEachClst",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "LookupClst",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('LookupClst').output.value",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "batchCount": 8,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "CpyClst",
                        "type": "Copy",
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false
                        },
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "DocumentDbCollectionSource",
                                "query": "select @{item()}",
                                "nestingSeparator": "."
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "type": "BlobSink"
                            },
                            "enableStaging": false,
                            "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true,
                            "cloudDataMovementUnits": 0
                        },
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "ClustersData",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "OutputClusters",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Example of doc in input collection (all the same format):

```
{
   "$type": "Entities.ADCluster",
    "DisplayName": "TESTNetBIOS",
    "OrgId": "9b679d2a-42c5-4c9a-a2e2-3ce63c1c3506",
    "ClusterId": "ab2a242d-f1a5-62ed-b420-31b52e958586",
    "AllowLdapLifeCycleSynchronization": true,
    "DirectoryServers": [
        {
            "$type": "Entities.DirectoryServer",
            "AddressId": "e6a8edbb-ad56-4135-94af-fab50b774256",
            "Port": 389,
            "Host": "192.168.342.234"
        }
    ],
    "DomainNames": [
        "TESTNetBIOS"
    ],
    "BaseDn": null,
    "UseSsl": false,
    "RepositoryType": 1,
    "DirectoryCustomizations": null,
    "_etag": "\"140046f2-0000-0000-0000-5ac63a180000\"",
    "LastUpdateTime": "2018-04-05T15:00:40.243Z",
    "id": "ab2a242d-f1a5-62ed-b420-31b52e958586",
    "PartitionKey": "directory-clusters-9b679d2a-42c5-4c9a-a2e2-3ce63c1c3506",
    "_rid": "kpvxLAs6gkmsCQAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/kvpxAA==/colls/kpvxLAs6gkk=/docs/kvpxALs6kgmsCQAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1522940440
}
```

Comment: From your payload, I can see it is generated by Copy Data Tool. And this pipeline should already copy each cosmos doc to a separate file in the same container. Could you double check? The only gap should be name it as {PartitionId}-{docId}?

Comment: i really did generated this with copy data tool, but for sure it merges all docs into single file. I checked my blob storage - 5 files for 5 collections, no more no less

Comment: P.S. I also tried to use foreach activity type as was mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554806/data-factory-v2-generate-a-json-file-per-row/49752944#comment88748501_49752944) but no lack( when I tried to create copy activity inside foreach activity - I can't select @item from foreach as a source for my copy activity

Comment: Oh sorry. I misunderstand that a collection is a doc. And currently, it is by design each collection to a single file. No sure whether your goal is supported.

Comment: I think answer of the post you mentioned should work. I will write it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your cosmosdb has array and ADF doesn't support serialize array for cosmos db, this is the workaround I can provide.

First, export all your document to json files with export json as-is (to blob or adls or file systems, any file storage). I think you already knows how to do it. In this way, each collection will have a json file.

Second, handle each json file, to exact each row in the file to a single file.

I only provide pipeline for step 2. You could use execute pipeline activity to chain step 1 and step 2. And you could even handle all the collections in step 2 with a foreach activity.

Pipeline json

```
{
"name": "pipeline27",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Lookup1",
            "type": "Lookup",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "BlobSource",
                    "recursive": true
                },
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "AzureBlob7",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "firstRowOnly": false
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach1",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Lookup1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Copy1",
                        "type": "Copy",
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false
                        },
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "DocumentDbCollectionSource",
                                "query": {
                                    "value": "select @{item()}",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "nestingSeparator": "."
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "type": "BlobSink"
                            },
                            "enableStaging": false,
                            "cloudDataMovementUnits": 0
                        },
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "DocumentDbCollection1",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "AzureBlob6",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "id": {
                                        "value": "@item().id",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "PartitionKey": {
                                        "value": "@item().PartitionKey",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
```

}

dataset json for lookup

```
   {
"name": "AzureBlob7",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "bloblinkedservice",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "typeProperties": {
        "format": {
            "type": "JsonFormat",
            "filePattern": "arrayOfObjects"
        },
        "fileName": "cosmos.json",
        "folderPath": "aaa"
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
```

}

Source dataset for copy. Actually, this dataset has no use. Just want to use it to host the query (select @{item()}

```
{
"name": "DocumentDbCollection1",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "CosmosDB-r8c",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "type": "DocumentDbCollection",
    "typeProperties": {
        "collectionName": "test"
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
```

}

Destination dataset. With two parameters, it also addressed your file name request.

```
{
"name": "AzureBlob6",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "AzureStorage-eastus",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "id": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "PartitionKey": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "typeProperties": {
        "format": {
            "type": "JsonFormat",
            "filePattern": "setOfObjects"
        },
        "fileName": {
            "value": "@{dataset().PartitionKey}-@{dataset().id}.json",
            "type": "Expression"
        },
        "folderPath": "aaacosmos"
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
```

}

please also note the limitation of Lookup activity:
The following data sources are supported for lookup. The maximum number of rows can be returned by Lookup activity is 5000, and up to 2MB in size. And currently the max duration for Lookup activity before timeout is one hour.

Comment: a lot of thanks! with your examples finally I was able to implement this =)

Comment: Thanks for taking this as answer. But since this actually copied data twice, it is actually not that efficient. You could also consider other ways if you need consider efficiency and other factors.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered implementing this in a different way using Azure Functions? ADF is designed for moving data in bulk from one place to another and only generates a single file per collection.

You could consider having an Azure Function that is triggered when documents are added / updated in your collection and have the Azure Function output the document to blob storage. This should scale well and would be relatively easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Just take one collection as an example.
[image]

And inside the foreach:
[image]

And your lookup and copy activity source dataset reference the same cosmosdb dataset.

If you want to copy your 5 collections, you could put this pipeline into an execute activity. And the master pipeline of the execute activity has a foreach activity.

Comment: a lot of thanks for your effort, gonna try right now =)

Comment: I've got an exception "Column: DirectoryServers&#44;The data type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray is not supported." Any idea how I can fix this? Actually, I don't want copy tool to parse my docs.. I just want them to be coppied as-is..  But when I check 'binary copy' - it says 'Binary copy between file-based stores and tabular dataset is not allowed.'

Comment: If you are using copy data tool, there is an export json as is check box. You could check it. If you are not using copy data tool, just clean all the column in schema tab for both source and sink dataset, and clean all the column mappings in mapping tab.

Comment: when I cleaned up schemas and run pipeline - i get an exception during run Column: DirectoryServers&#44;The data type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray is not supported. DirectoryServers field in original cosmos doc looks like: `"DirectoryServers": [
        {
            "$type": "Entities.DirectoryServer",
            "AddressId": "e6a8edbb-da56-4185-94af-fab504074256",
            "Port": 389,
            "Host": "192.168.122.141"
        }`

Comment: btw, in my datasource after run appear excluded columns in the source : https://www.screencast.com/t/DP3AK9yE3

Comment: Could you share me the pipeline and dataset json? Is structrue still in your dataset json? Please check both input and output. And also clean the mappings.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've updated the post with pipeline and json example

Comment: Hi Olga,  the problem is not the copy Activity. It is because the lookup activity has already failed since ADF doesn’t support serializs array.  ( you could set the breakpoint in UI to just test the lookup activity) In that case, I think my solution won’t work. You may need consider other solutions. Maybe you could export them as is out to json files first and handle the json files.

Comment: And the excluded columns actually doesn’t matter if you want to export json as is. Click the clear button will clean them all.

Comment: Added another answer to handle array.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled a bit with this, especially getting around the size limits of the Lookup activity, since we have a LOT of data to migrate. I ended up creating a JSON file with a list of timestamps to query the Cosmos data with, then for each of those, getting the document IDs in that range, and then for each of those, getting the full document data and saving it to a path such as `PartitionKey/DocumentID`. Here's the pipelines I created:

LookupTimestamps - loops through each timestamp range from a `times.json` file, and for each timestamp, executes the ExportFromCosmos pipeline

```
{
    "name": "LookupTimestamps",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "LookupTimestamps",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BlobSource",
                        "recursive": false
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "BlobStorageTimestamps",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEachTimestamp",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "LookupTimestamps",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('LookupTimestamps').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": false,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "ExportFromCosmos",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                "parameters": {
                                    "From": {
                                        "value": "@{item().From}",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "To": {
                                        "value": "@{item().To}",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

ExportFromCosmos - nested pipeline that's executed from the above pipeline. This is to get around the fact you can't have nested ForEach activities.

```
{
    "name": "ExportFromCosmos",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "LookupDocuments",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DocumentDbCollectionSource",
                        "query": {
                            "value": "select c.id, c.partitionKey from c where c._ts >= @{pipeline().parameters.from} and c._ts <= @{pipeline().parameters.to} order by c._ts desc",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "nestingSeparator": "."
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "CosmosDb",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEachDocument",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "LookupDocuments",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('LookupDocuments').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DocumentDbCollectionSource",
                                    "query": {
                                        "value": "select * from c where c.id = \"@{item().id}\" and c.partitionKey = \"@{item().partitionKey}\"",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "nestingSeparator": "."
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "BlobSink"
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "CosmosDb",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "BlobStorageDocuments",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "id": {
                                            "value": "@item().id",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "partitionKey": {
                                            "value": "@item().partitionKey",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "from": {
                "type": "int"
            },
            "to": {
                "type": "int"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BlobStorageTimestamps - dataset for the `times.json` file

```
{
    "name": "BlobStorageTimestamps",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureBlobStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "typeProperties": {
            "format": {
                "type": "JsonFormat",
                "filePattern": "arrayOfObjects"
            },
            "fileName": "times.json",
            "folderPath": "mycollection"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

BlobStorageDocuments - dataset for where the documents will be saved

```
{
    "name": "BlobStorageDocuments",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureBlobStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "partitionKey": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "typeProperties": {
            "format": {
                "type": "JsonFormat",
                "filePattern": "arrayOfObjects"
            },
            "fileName": {
                "value": "@{dataset().partitionKey}/@{dataset().id}.json",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "folderPath": "mycollection"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

The times.json file it just a list of epoch times and looks like this:

```
[{
    "From": 1556150400,
    "To": 1556236799
},
{
    "From": 1556236800,
    "To": 1556323199
}]
```