# Azure Data Factory 2 Dynamic Mapping In Copy Activity UI

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create a pipeline in Azure Data Factory 2 that takes a CSV file for example and convert it to JSON format.

The problem is beside converting the file's format I also want to apply some conditions based on other fields.

For example:

**CSV:**

```
Column1, Column2, Column3   
"SomeValue", "true", "N/A"
```

**JSON (Schema):**

```
{"firstValue": null, "secondValue": null}
```

**Now what I'm trying to achieve is the following mapping,**

```
Column1 (CSV) **--->** firstValue (JSON)     
Column1 == true || Column3 != "N/A" **--->** secondValue (JSON)
```

Hope this example is clear enough, basically, I'm trying to achieve dynamic mapping through the UI, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no easy way to implement this simply with a copy activity.
But you may achieve this with lookup activity + foreach activity + copy activity.
You could take a look of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872649/how-to-copy-%D0%A1osmosdb-docs-to-blob-storage-each-doc-in-single-json-file-with-az). You could provide a fake source dataset and just use a query to achieve your map.