# Create Blobs with Filename and Data from SQL Rows

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

There is plenty of documentation on how to use Azure Data Factory to read data from blobs into SQL, and even documentation on how to dump the output of a query to a single blob. I'm trying to create one blob for each row in a table (on Azure SQL Server), named by one field and containing the data in another.

My table has a GUID `id` field and a nvarchar(max) `data` field (which contains JSON, though that's largely irrelevant). Suppose I have the following rows:

```
                 id                    |  data
---------------------------------------+----------
38b2f551-5f13-40ce-8512-c108a05ecd44   |  foo
4db5b25b-1194-44e9-a7b2-bc8889c32979   |  bar
2a3bd653-ce14-4bd2-9243-6923e97224c6   |  baz
```

I want the following blobs to be created:

```
https://mycontainer.blob.core.windows.net/myblobs/38b2f551-5f13-40ce-8512-c108a05ecd44
https://mycontainer.blob.core.windows.net/myblobs/4db5b25b-1194-44e9-a7b2-bc8889c32979
https://mycontainer.blob.core.windows.net/myblobs/2a3bd653-ce14-4bd2-9243-6923e97224c6
```

Their contents should be the associated data field, i.e. `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, respectively.

[Data Factory v2 - Generate a json file per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554806/data-factory-v2-generate-a-json-file-per-row) has an answer that will work, but it involves querying the database once to get all the `id`s, then **N** more times to get the data from each row. It seems like it should be possible to query just once for both fields and use one for filename and one for contents, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty simple feat natively in ADF:

1. Use a Lookup Activity to get the row results of your Database Table
2. Use a For Each to Iterate over each row from the Lookup
3. Within the For Each have a Copy Data activity that copies from DB (as a passthrough really) to Blob Storage

Here are screenshots with comments to illustrate the exact steps and proof that it works:

**1st, here is my mock table that is similar to your example, I have a pretend FileID, and Data field**

[image: Mock Table]

**2nd, I do a lookup on that table, see the details and output below**
[image: Lookup Activity Example]

**3rd, we put in the For Each activity so that we can perform an action or group of actions per item in the array object**

[image: For each Example]

**4th, we go into the For each and create a Copy Data activity with a Source of Azure SQLDB and a Sink of Azure Blob**

Source Details:
[image: Copy Data Source]

Sink Details:
[image: Copy Data Sink]

**And here is what happens in my Blob Storage when I run this pipeline:**

[image: Proof it works]

Let me know if you need anything else or have any questions, hope this helps! Remember to like, love, and follow :)

Comment: I should add some caveats here... If your table is going to have more than 5k rows, then you will have to break up the lookup into multiple activities, which can still be done, but complicates things. Also, this method is using Azure SQLDB as a passthrough with the SELECT statement, and I believe the max length of the data contents can only be 64k characters, but since your contents are stored in Azure DB already, I don't see an issue there unless you are using a CLOB field or something.

Answer (score 0):

After studying the case [Data Factory v2 - Generate a json file per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554806/data-factory-v2-generate-a-json-file-per-row), i suggestion you don't stick to copy activity.Based on your description,you could consider below solution:

1.Use [GetMetaData Avtivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) which can be used to retrieve metadata of any data in Azure Data Factory.You could get all your blob files' metadata by using this [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#get-a-folders-metadata).

2.Use [ForEach Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) to loop the file names.

3.In ForEach Activity,run [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) to call [Http Trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook). Pass the file name to the Azure Function as parameter. In the function method, please use [azure blob storage sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=windows) to retrieve content by the file name. Then insert the total row into sql database by [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/sql?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: You have it backward. I am not trying to go from blob to SQL, I am trying to go from SQL to blobs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the copy activity directly, you could  use a for-each activity to route each row of your sql lookup to a rest api call for the blob storage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob).  Or some other way of writing.